# Create a tensor based on another tensor in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following tensor:

```py
indices = tf.constant([[1, 2], [0, 2], [1, 0]])
```

and I would like to create the following tensor:

```
[[0, 1, 1],
 [1, 0, 1],
 [1, 1, 0]]
```

Basically, I want a square matrix with the shape of `indices.shape[0]` where its elements are all zero except in the corresponding indices in `indices` tensor.

I tried `tf.scatter_nd` but no luck!

Comment: Depending on your data flow, you might find it useful to use [sparse tensors](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/sparse_tensor#creating_a_tfsparsetensor). Note that the format of your matrix is very similar to the the repsentation of sparse tensors. When needed, sparse tensors can be converted to usual ones by calling `sparse.to_dense' method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `indices` tensor carries some implicit information that you should make explicit. For `scatter_nd` to work, you need to provide some pairs `(i,j)`, where `i` is the index of the first dimension, and `j` the index of the second dimension.

You can restructure you `indices` Tensor the following way:

```
indices = tf.constant([[1, 2], [0, 2], [1, 0]])
j_indices = tf.reshape(indices, [-1, 1])
i_indices = tf.expand_dims(tf.repeat(tf.range(3), 2), axis=-1)
new_indices = tf.concat([i_indices, j_indices], axis=-1)
```

New indices contains the `(i,j)` indexes:

```
>>> new_indices
<tf.Tensor: shape=(6, 2), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[0, 1],
       [0, 2],
       [1, 0],
       [1, 2],
       [2, 1],
       [2, 0]], dtype=int32)>
```

And you can use that with `scatter_nd`:

```
>>> tf.scatter_nd(new_indices, updates=tf.ones(tf.shape(new_indices)[0]), shape=[3, 3])
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[0., 1., 1.],
       [1., 0., 1.],
       [1., 1., 0.]], dtype=float32)>
```